# Skipping a test based on the pass of a previous test

Tags: django, nose

I'm using the django test suite with nose and trying to figure out how I can run a followup test if a previous test fails. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:

1. Have a global variable called `test_condition_a = False` shared among test cases.
2. Try/catch assert in `test_a` and catch the exception when it fails so that you can set `test_condition_a = True` before the test exits.
3. Use `@unittest.skipIf(test_condition_a)` on all other test cases that you want run only if `test_a` fails.

**EDIT** On second thought, the above is not going to work as the test order is random. Your best bet would be to do something like this

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...

    @unittest.skip("Skip by default")
    def testB(self):
        #test code

    def testA(self):
        try:
            #test code
            return True
        except Error:
            return False

    def testA_then_B(self):
        if (self.testA()):
            self.testB()
```

Comment: My only issues with the code above is it doesn't handle running testB if testA fails. I could catch exceptions in testA, but then I don't know at what point to push to exceptions back out to the test framework.

Comment: Sorry, typo. `if(not self.testA()) self.testB()`. How does that sound?